# Async / Lazy Load Vue components with browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, vue.js, laravel-elixir, vue-router

I am trying to load a number of Vue.js components into my app.js file (using browserify/vueify via elixir) in a laravel project.

Instead of loading every component at once, I'd like to lazy load the individual vue components when they are needed using [vue router](http://router.vuejs.org/en/lazy.html#browserify).

Where do I set up the **`partition bundle json`** file and how should it be structured?

At the moment, Ive tied out the following an my main **app.js** file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Resource from 'vue-resource';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

// These are the components that I wish to lazy load:
// import Users from './components/Users.vue';
// import Sales from './components/Sales.vue';
// import Projects from './components/Projects.vue';
// import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard.vue';
// import Receipts from './components/Receipts.vue';

Vue.use(Resource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

var router = new VueRouter();

router.map({
  '/async': {
    component: function (resolve) {
      loadjs(['./components/Users.vue'], resolve)
    }
  }
})
```

**Here's where I am stuck:**

1. How do we lazy load all .vue components listed above in the **`router.map`** function?
2. How to set up the **`partition table json`** file for the above, and where should it be saved?

Comment: Pretty old question but if anyone needs more information to lazy loading components. Here is a link to the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components

> If you’re a **Browserify** user that would like to use async components, its creator has unfortunately made it clear that **async loading “is not something that Browserify will ever support.”** Officially, at least. The Browserify community has found some workarounds, which may be helpful for existing and complex applications. For all other scenarios, **we recommend simply using Webpack** for built-in, first-class async support.